# PHP, Rails 2 and Rails 3 on the same server, on production mode

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, apache-2.2, rvm

I am setting up a new web server (ubuntu 10.04 LTS), I want to get run on production mode: PHP, Rails 2.3.X and Rails 3, and each one should be accessible from diferent path, ex:

http://localhost/rails2_project

http://localhost/rails3_project

http://localhost/php_project

running the three at the time.

I already have installed rvm (with ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.2), Apache, PHP and MySQL (I use MySQL for Rails and PHP applications).

Some suggest, documentation, links?... are all welcome

Comment: Hello, I don't understand, which is the problem with my question? I do not expect you to do my job, it's just that I have looked online and there are many different documents, I would like you to recommend me a reliable documentation because I want to start right from the beginning.

Comment: @el_quik - as I said. There is nothing *wrong* with your question, it's just been asked on the wrong site. Your question is about setting up software. That sort of question is better put on ServerFault, instead of StackOverflow.

Comment: Several of us have already voted for it to be moved over there by a moderator - so it should get moved there very soon now and then you'll get the help you need.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use apache2 mod_alias : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html

A better approach than using urls like http://localhost/somepath is : using virtualhosts
you can define in your /etc/hosts file this entry

```
127.0.0.1  rails2 rails3 php
```

and then define name based virtualhosts for each project so that you can user urls like

http://rails2, http://rails3 and http://php